# How unique is mails conversation index property of the email

Tags: email, smtp, exchange-server

I am using Exchange Server Webservices Managed API to move all mails belonging to same conversation thread to a specific folder. Folder for first mail in the conversation is specified by the user which is when I store its conversation index and folder name in database. Subsequent mails in the conversation should be moved to the same folder by the code automatically.

My problem is if it is possible that conversation index of two mails can be same if the conversation is originated from two different servers possibly of two different type. For example if the user have Exchange Account and sends a mail creating a `conversation thread 1`. Also a user receives a mail 
from Lotus Server creating a `conversation thread 2`. Is it possible that `conversation thread 1` and `conversation thread 2` can have same conversation index?

Comment: Based on your other post, are you using the ConversationIndex because the ConversationId isn't available to you in Ex2007?

Comment: Yess I am using ConversationIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glen Scales answered this on the [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2f698b6-8a96-44c8-9ba6-930b1f42431a/how-unique-is-mails-conversation-index-property-of-the-email?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment): You can check how the property is computed at  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202481(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202481%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) , because it contains a GUID it should be relative safe to assume it will be unique but GUIDs themselves are never guaranteed to be unique. The ConversationId property is another matter [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee204279(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee204279%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) as that is computed from the pidTagConversationThread property which is just the Message Subject.

Comment: so is it reliable to implement this functionality using `ConversationIndex` or some more care can be taken? If yess what sort of?